# JQuery .post() sending data in one script, but not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

First, yes, I am a beginner, so please dont go to hard on me for not knowing. Second, I am not using the AJAX method.

So my problem stems from having my client talk to my server, and I implemented some code I found here:

- Serverside:

```
    app.post("/request", (req, res) => {
        let data = req.body;
        console.log(data);
        if (objectlistlength && objectlistlength != (0 || 'unset')) {
            objectlist.push(data);
            objectlistlength--;
        };
        if (objectlistlength == 'unset') {
            console.log(objectlistlength, data)
            objectlistlength = data.repeat;
        };
        if (objectlistlength == 0) {
            objectlist = JSON.stringify(objectlist);
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'website', 'static', 'json', 'maps.json'), `${objectlist}`);
            objectlist = [];
            objectlistlength = 'unset';
        };
     });
```

- Client:

```
    let init = {
        repeat: list.length
    };
    $.post("/request", init, () => {console.log(init)});
    for(let x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
        $.post("/request", list[x]);
        console.log(list[x]);
    };
```

The thing is, I have the exact same snippits of code on 2 separate projects; on one it works fine, and it gives a JSON list of objects. On another, `req.body` returns as undefined. This problem has been going on since I implemented the list code (and I'm not gonna use another one even if its cleaner - is a project for fun, so I dont care about cleanliness). The POST just refuses to return an item of data to the server, but only on that one project. Whats going wrong? Did I not install a library correctly, or something?

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to register some middleware like `app.use(express.urlencoded())`

Comment: FYI `$.post()` is just short-hand for `$.ajax({ method: "POST" })`

Comment: *I am not using _the_ AJAX method* - do you mean not using `$.ajax` method?  Because `$.post()` is one of many jquery AJAX methods (and as noted above, just shorthand)

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know they were the same thing, thank you! Also yes, I did forget to use the `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true }))` line. Thanks y'all!